# Keyboard Issue for Asus Vivobook Flip TP 412U

Tags: keyboard, asus

I just installed Ubuntu 18 LTS on my Asus Vivobook flip and almost everything works perfectly. The one exception is the keyboard--it seems that only the function keys (fn + f4) are working right now. I'm dual booting with Windows, and the laptop keyboard works well when choosing between Windows and Ubuntu. Also works well when editing the BIOS.

I've searched around but can't figure out what's causing this issue. The keyboard is totally unresponsive besides the aforementioned fn keys. I've tried

```
service keyboard-setup restart
```

to no avail. I've also tried editing grub which seems to make things worse (breaks touchpad and fn keys). I've also tried,

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`
but that didn't help. Does anyone have any other ideas that might work?

Comment: Have you installed in UEFI mode or Legacy?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'm not sure. I followed the instructions [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3) and the instructions say "Bios (or UEFI-CSM)". I would guess UEFI.

Comment: Actually no, if you kept those default settings. For UEFI you need GPT/UEFI. So, the one you created boots in Legacy mode and that's how you installed and that's the beginning of all sorts of problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help—the keyboard does not work when booting into Ubuntu (besides the fn keys) even when I have a UEFI bootable drive. Previously I was able to install using the on screen keyboard. Now I’m beginning to think the problem might be related to something else. Any thoughts given the update above?

Comment: You're the first one reporting such problem. Start by updating the UEFI if  there's an update available.

Comment: Updated UEFI but no dice. It seems like this user had a similar issue:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123595/my-keyboard-not-working-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1

Are there any other steps to try? Thinking about switching distros. Would the newer version be worth trying?

Comment: Yes, it's worth trying 19.04. Hopefully the new kernel 5.x has support already.

Comment: TY @GabrielaGarcia. Version 19 works perfectly. So, it seems like this was just a matter of getting an updated kernel.

Comment: :) At last something that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several attempts at troubleshooting the current 18.04 release and after updating the firmware (UEFI) the problem persisted. The conclusion is that the kernel of that release has poor support for this hardware.

Installing 19.04 provided the proper support for the detachable keyboard that the previous release/kernel lacks.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Installing 19.04 only solved it.